# CSS style attaching to wrong element

Tags: css

Given this code,

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progressbar{
  counter-reset: step;
}

.progressbar li{
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  list-style:none
}

.progressbar li:before{
  content:counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #bebebe;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 27px;
  background: white;
  color: #bebebe;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.progressbar li:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #979797;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li:first-child::after{
content: none;
}

.progressbar li.active + li::after{
 background: #3aac5d;
}
.progressbar li.active + li::before{
border-color: #3aac5d;
background: #3aac5d;
color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
     <div class="container">
         <ul class="progressbar">
            <li>Accept a halter and be willing to be lead</li>
   <li>Allow its feet to be picked up for cleaning or trimming</li>
   <li class="active">Stand and be willing to be groomed</li>
   <li>Be willing to load quietly in a trailer</ li>
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

When i view it in browser, the 'active' class attaches to the wrong element. For instance 'active' is on third `<li>` but displays on the fourth.  Cant figure out why. I am sure there is a simple explanation but i am at a loss. I have been working on it for hrs and cant seem to see the issue.

Comment: `li.active + li` means "style the `li` right after `li.active`", so in your case, the third `li` triggers styling on the next sibling, the fourth `li`.

Answer (score 0):

The + li means the next li .. to correct the styling you would do :

```
.progressbar li.active::after{
 background: #3aac5d;
}
.progressbar li.active::before{
border-color: #3aac5d;
background: #3aac5d;
color: white
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` selector is used to select a element that are placed immediately after the specified element. See [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

If you want to color the third element, just remove the plus selector.

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progressbar{
  counter-reset: step;
}

.progressbar li{
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  list-style:none
}

.progressbar li:before{
  content:counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #bebebe;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 27px;
  background: white;
  color: #bebebe;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.progressbar li:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #979797;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li:first-child::after{
content: none;
}

.progressbar li.active::after{
 background: #3aac5d;
}
.progressbar li.active::before{
border-color: #3aac5d;
background: #3aac5d;
color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
     <div class="container">
         <ul class="progressbar">
            <li>Accept a halter and be willing to be lead</li>
   <li>Allow its feet to be picked up for cleaning or trimming</li>
   <li class="active">Stand and be willing to be groomed</li>
   <li>Be willing to load quietly in a trailer</ li>
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```